# Getting this error when adding new data... Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, dispatchgroup

So when I'm loading up my App for the first time and I'm adding in my first piece of data, the tableView reloads and the section/rows are added properly, but when I enter in any additional data after that, the new data gets added but my original data gets duplicated in my tableView (not in the backend), furthermore, if I'm adding in data under the same Section, my app crashes and I get the error that I have in my title.

Looking to get some insight on this. This is my first Firestore App and I'm still trying to figure it out.

EDIT 1: I tried removing the two snapshot Listeners and that solved my error problem, but my data still get's duplicated...

EDIT 2: Nevermind. I figured it out. I had the dataArray as a global variable that I kept appending to.

[image]
[image]

```
struct Workouts: Decodable {
    var workout : String     
  }

struct Days: Decodable {
     var dow : String
    var workouts : [Workouts] 
  }



var dayCount = 0

var dataArray = [Days]()


    //MARK: - viewDidLoad()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        vcBackgroundImg()
        navConAcc()

        picker.delegate = self
        picker.dataSource = self

        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellID)
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

        Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
            self.userIdRef = user!.uid
            self.rootCollection = Firestore.firestore().collection("/users/\(self.userIdRef)/Days")

            self.loadData { (Bool) in
                if Bool == true {
                    self.dayCount = self.dataArray.count
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }

        }

    }



    //MARK: - Load Data
    func loadData(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()){

        let group = DispatchGroup()

        self.rootCollection.addSnapshotListener ({ (snapshot, err) in

            if let err = err
            {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err.localizedDescription)");
            }
            else {

                guard let dayDocument = snapshot?.documents else { return }

                for day in dayDocument {

                    group.enter()

                    self.rootCollection.document(day.documentID).collection("Workouts").addSnapshotListener{(snapshot, err) in

                        var workouts = [Workouts]()

                        let workoutDocument = snapshot!.documents

                        try! workoutDocument.forEach({doc in

                            let tester: Workouts = try doc.decoded()
                            let workoutString = tester.workout
                            let newWorkout = Workouts(workout: workoutString)
                            workouts.append(newWorkout)
                        })

                        let dayTitle = day.data()["dow"] as! String

                        let newDay = Days(dow: dayTitle, workouts: workouts)

                        self.dataArray.append(newDay)

                        group.leave()
                    }

                }

            }
            group.notify(queue: .main){
                completion(true)
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Instead of adding screenshots of your code/error, please add the actual error message, which you can get by right clicking on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".

Comment: I added another screenshot of of the Debug Navigator. It doesn't show nay issues in the Issue Navigator.

Comment: That's helpful. Thanks. I don't immediately see what's going wrong here, so hope that someone else spots it.

Comment: Maybe related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39188005/dispatch-group-crashing-because-asynchronous-function-executes-multiple-time

Comment: I tried removing the two snapshot Listeners and that solved my error problem, but my data still get's duplicated...

Comment: Nevermind. I figured it out. I had the dataArray as a global variable that I kept appending to.